# How to tailor input sources? Need Hiragana, but don't need Katakana

Tags: keyboard, input-source

(This is for MacOS Monterey)

In the MacOS status bar I can set the keyboard schema, which currently contains the following menu items:

- ABC - QWERTZ
- German
- Romaji
- Hiragana
- Katakana

In practice, I would need only German and Hiragana. How I remove the other ones only? In particular, I can't remove Japanese completely, because this would remove the Hiragana entry as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the boxes for the other modes in the settings for Japanese Romaji.

[image]

Comment: I see. First I had the impression that it would not work, but I understood than that it took one minute or so, until the changes are reflected in the tool bar!